# excel index match return unique value (no duplication) top 3 list

Tags: excel

i need some help as getting confuse after googling various method of 'index match' with array, my question is how to do index match with returning unique value or no duplicate value in a top3 list?

eg. in below top5 list (C1 area), no. 2 & 3 have same name 'abc' instead of 'abc' and 'aab' because of same value 23.

Would appreciate someone can enlighten me, thank you.

```
ID   , area ,    Sales

abc  , c1     ,   23

def   ,c3     ,   8

aab  , c1     ,   23

ddf  , c2     ,   33

xxc  , c1        43
```

,

```
Top 5 (C1 area)

No     , ID

1   ,    xxc

2    ,   abc

3    ,   abc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm understanding, you have multiple values you want to return back because there are duplicates.

You can do this.

Here's an example:

[image]

1. Fill Column A with the lookup reference you want to match against. In this example, we’ll use type of Animal.
2. Fill Column B with values you want the formula to return. If this example, we’ll use Name.
3. Enter this formula:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))`

4. Make sure you press CONTROL-SHIFT-ENTER in the cell to convert it to an Array Formula!
5. Copy the formula down to allow it to list the subsequent matches, if any.

How does it work? Well, the SMALL() section of the Array Formula identifies the row numbers that match your selection. It uses the row number to return the value in that row only. When you copy the formula down, it automatically jumps to the next matching row number and returns that value, until it can’t find anything and errors out (resulting in a blank cell).

You can download this excel example [here](http://eimagine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/eimagine-Excel-Multiple-Matches.xlsx)

Remember to do ctrl+shift+enter on any modification to the formula.

this was the article I referred to: http://eimagine.com/how-to-return-multiple-match-values-in-excel-using-index-match-or-vlookup/

Comment: Hi Pavan Katepalli, thank you so much for sharing, very helpful, i will try them, thanks.

Comment: hey robin let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Hi, if i want to add one more lookup criteria, eg. in your animal table, to look up another new column C for 'area' based on cell G1, how to add this in the coding? Thanks

Comment: hey robin you could copy the formula and run it another cell and then change $A$1:$A$8 to $C$1:$C$8 all over. If this helped, consider marking my answer correct :)

Comment: Hi, in your excel example, what if i have added extra info in c1:c8 as 'area', and i i want to add a new lookup value by refering c1:c8 range in cell H1, so there are now two lookup value in E1 & H1, how can i edit the code below? Thanks

{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))}